# How to delete all entries in a table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

My named query looked like this `delete from User u` without a where clause, but it didn't delete anything on a `Query.executeUpdate()`

Comment: Please show the complete source code which should run the delete. `sessionFactory.openSession()`, `session.beginTransaction()`, `tx.commit()`, etc.

Comment: I think this might solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381040/unexpected-end-of-subtree-exception-after-hibernate-version-update-on-delete-que

Answer (score 0):

try *DELETE FROM com.VERY_LONG_PATH.TestTable*. And you have to check catchers of exceptions.. maybe you haven't seen some exceptions

Answer (score 0):

nothing works for me, just a FindAll and delete 1 by 1.