# unexpected end of subtree exception after Hibernate version update on delete query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I get a strange exception when I delete all data from a table. The exception occurs since I updated the Hibernate version from 3.x.x to 4.2.6.

the Dao method that I call to delete the data from the table:

```
  @Override
  public void deleteAll()
  {
     EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
     em.createQuery( "DELETE Document" ).executeUpdate();
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
12:46:03,570 ERROR ErrorCounter:50 - <AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
<AST>:0:0: unexpected end of subtree
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.whereClauseExpr(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1378)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.SqlGeneratorBase.whereClause(SqlGeneratorBase.java:1272)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.exec.DeleteExecutor.<init>(DeleteExecutor.java:72)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.buildAppropriateStatementExecutor(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:535)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:201)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:105)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:168)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:221)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:199)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1778)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor800.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "document" )
public class Document implements Serializable
{
  @Override
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  @Column( name = "document_id" )
  private int           id;

  private String                 filename;

  @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
  @Column( name = "file_modified_time" )
  private Date                   fileModifiedTime;

  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
  @JoinColumn( name = "attached_to_Task_fk" )
  private Task       attachedToTaskFk;

 //Getter/Setter
}
```

When I add a where clause to the delete query, the exception doesn't occur.

```
em.createQuery( "DELETE Document d WHERE d.id > 0" ).executeUpdate();
```

But I don't think that Hibernate intended it this way.

I already checked following topics:

- [unexpected end of subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066361/hibernate-and-unexpected-end-of-subtree-exception)
- [Hibernate and Unexpected end of Subtree exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066361/hibernate-and-unexpected-end-of-subtree-exception)

Has anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Still no fix yet, but maybe in near future you might find a solution here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8603

Comment: Have you tried to downgrade and upgrade the hibernate version?

Comment: You have anything to cascade? 

Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13210638/hibernate-delete-query

Comment: Have you tried to put the Query in a NamedQuery?

Comment: @Andrei: NamedQuery doesen't work. Downgrade to Hibernate version 4.1.9 and the exception will not appear.

Comment: @Seffel OK, then could you use Hibernate 4.1.9 as long as the error in the Hibernate version 4.2.X is not fixed? Watch the issue in the link in the first comment from user "ymene" in order to get updates to the current status of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [Hibernate bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8578) that is fixed in 4.2.7 and 4.3.0.Beta5. The DeleteExecutor previously required a Where clause.

You can find the [patch](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/e3419f6d722a276fd846178ee59b3176a9fb0da7) on GitHub if you're not ready to upgrade to 4.2.7.